# Why can't I call function but I can print it in console? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following function:

```
      var groceries = ["toothpaste", ["plums", "peaches", "pineapples"], ["carrots", "corn", "green beans"], "orange juice", ["chocolate", "ice cream"], "paper towels", "fish"];
      console.log("groceries", groceries);

      function removeItems(arr, toRemove) {
        function createKey(item) {
          return Array.isArray(item) ? item.join('-') : item;
        }

        var removeDict = toRemove.reduce(function(d, item) {
          var key = createKey(item);
          d[key] = true;

          return d;
        }, {});

        console.log("removeDict", removeDict);

        return arr.filter(function(item) {
          var key = createKey(item);

          return !removeDict[key];
        });
      }

      var result = removeItems(groceries, ["fish", "orange juice", ["chocolate", "ice cream"]]);

      console.log("result", result);
```

(This comes from this previous question I asked):
[function to remove single items or arrays from within an array - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902773/function-to-remove-single-items-or-arrays-from-within-an-array-javascript/45902961#45902961)

If I create a variable at the end that calls the function, it prints in the console correctly.

However, if I try to call the function directly, like this:

```
removeItems(groceries, ["fish", "orange juice", ["chocolate", "ice cream"]]);

console.log("groceries", groceries);
```

The items do not get removed. Why can't I call the function directly? Am I missing something?

Comment: because the function returns a new array, which you are discarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array filter method returns a new filtered array.

Therefore, your original array is not mutated.

If you store the result in a variable, you can then log that instead:

```
var newArr = removeItems(groceries, ["fish", "orange juice", ["chocolate", "ice cream"]]);

console.log("groceries", newArr)
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad this helped you out.